Wife and her best friend murder husband movie
I saw this movie once but would like to watch it again.
It's a gory movie about a wife that suspects her husband has robbed a bank and has all the money and plans on giving her nothing. She then asks her best friend, Tiny, to help interrogate her husband. They tie him to a chair and ask questions and 'accidentally' the Wife shoots the husband right through the head. They freak out but then plot ways to get rid of his body. They decide on chopping him up into tiny pieces and scattering these pieces all over. The wife makes the best friend chop the body up.
After they get rid of the body they realize the house looks like a bloodbath and get to cleaning it. As they are busy a police officer comes by and asks about the where-abouts of the husband and suspects something is going on. He decides to wait for a warrant to search the house and waits and watches the house from a distance. The women then decide to make a run for it if they can find the money and start new lives. They search everywhere but come up empty.
Just then another thief/murderer breaks into the house looking for the husband and wanting to take the money he stole. At gunpoint the women confess what has happened so far and that they don't know where the money is. Then Wife admits to Tiny she knew about the affair Tiny had with her husband and that she made her cut up her lover on purpose. Now it is suspected the wife knows where the money is and has played the best friend all along. Besides all that they both work together and kill the intruder.
Afterwards the wife accuses her friend more and then murders her. The wife then cleans up herself and puts on gardening gear and goes to the front lawn and waves to the watching cop. She then uproots flowers and one then sees she hid rolls of the stolen money under newly planted flower in the garden. She carries her 'flower' basket inside and takes the money out and rolls some up and puts the rolls in her hair curlers which she puts in her hair. She cleans herself up some more and then cuts of her ring finger. She then goes out the back entrance and walks away from the house covered in blood.
Later on cops come to investigate with a warrant and are shocked at the scene.
It is shown later the wife climbs in the car of her new lover and accomplice the first cop that asked questions. They celebrate getting away with everything and ride off into the distance. 

How long is "a long time ago"? Also, could you please break this up into a few paragraphs? As is, it's a bit difficult to read :)

@madmada Is there a reason why you created a partagraph each individual sentence?

@Napoleon Wilson ♦ Thought it's an easy to read  formatting (Short separate Paragraphs)

Sounds like "Breathless" (2012)
Plot:

"Lorna (Gina Gershon, SHOWGIRLS, P.S. I LOVE YOU) is a strong-willed Texas woman who's had enough of her untrustworthy husband Dale's (Val Kilmer, TOP GUN, BATMAN FOREVER) criminal acts and lack of husbandry. Fed up, she enlists the help of her old friend, Tiny (Kelli Giddish, NBC's "Law & Order: Special Victims Unit"), to help her figure out what to do with Dale after his latest double-cross involving the theft of $100,000 from a bank. As the girls brainstorm for a "neat" solution, they medicate themselves with only the best of prescriptions - Tennessee whiskey - which leads them to even bigger problems. When Sheriff Cooley (Ray Liotta, GOODFELLAS, HANNIBAL) inconveniently enters the conundrum, the story evolves into a tale of revenge and survival that resolves in true Texas fashion: bold and ruthless."

Preview:



